# Accessing multidimensional array in Php

Tags: php, json, api, multidimensional-array, plagiarism-detection

I print the multidimensional array which I get from an API and the goal is to loop over the array and check of the field [Percents] is greater than 20 but with no success: This is how the array looks like:
[Multidimensional array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsBwV.jpg)

How do I get the number which appears right after the word Percents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Percents as below:

```
foreach($arrays as $array){
    if(isset($array->Percents){
        echo $array->Percents;
    }
}
```

Here, I am echoing the percents, you can even put it in some other variables.

Answer (score 0):

In this array, the first index is an object of Copyleaks\ResultRecord. So you would need to access it like below.

```
$array[0]->Percents;
```

If you are looping then

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $value->Percents; //Percents that you are looking for
}
```